# Why does Sql Sum of multiple columns containing nulls return incorrect result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Table containing the following values:

```
Column1  Column2
1        NULL
NULL     4
2        NULL
NULL     5
3        6
```

The following query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM([Column1] + [Column2] ) 
FROM [myTable]
```

returns a value of `9` when it should be returning `21`. Why? How does it arrive at the value?

I know the SUM can be corrected by adding `ISNULL` like so:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ISNULL([Column1], 0) + ISNULL([Column2], 0)) 
FROM [myTable]
```

but I would like to know the logic behind the value `9`

Comment: What is the sum of `null` and a number, exactly? Note where the `9` comes from: the only row which has non-null `Column1` _and_ `Column2`.

Comment: @MattBall Yes! I see now, the calculation skips any row that has a null column1 or column2. If you add that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the sum of `null` and a number, exactly? Note where the `9` comes from: the only row which has non-null `Column1` and `Column2`.

[One viable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13132245/139010) has of course already been posted. But then, where's the fun in jumping right to the fix?

(copypasta'd at OP's request)

Comment: I marked this as the answer as it was the first to explain the logic of where the 9 comes from.

Answer (score 7):

use `COALESCE` to convert *null* into `0`. (*that's it if you want null values as zero.*)

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(column1,0) + COALESCE(column2,0))
FROM table1
```

- [***See SQLFIDDLE Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c352/7)

Answer (score 3):

Because it is adding value +NULL before summing

Try sum(column1) + sum(column2)

Comment: This is a nice alternative to the ISNULL/COALESCE suggestions by others. Note, however, that if one column had no values at all (only NULLs), this would evaluate to NULL. I would still prefer ISNULLing the result of SUM than its argument(s), though, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ISNULL function to get the desired behavior:

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Column1, 0) + ISNULL(Column2, 0)) FROM [myTable]
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a problem with a Null value.

```
SELECT SUM(IsNull(Column1, 0) + IsNull(Column2, 0) ) FROM [myTable]
```

to ensure it is always 0 at minimum.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. number + NULL = NULL
2. SUM(**expression**) function is manipulated by calculating the **expression** by each row separately and return **a NOT_NULL value**. And then all the results will be summed and returned.

That's reason why your result is 9.
**ISNULL(expression, replacement_value)** can help you in this situation. :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative explanation (just in case it works better for someone):

NULLs affect `+` but do not affect `SUM()`: where a NULL is `+`-ed, it evaluates to NULL, where it is SUMmed, it is ignored. (But `SUM()` *can* return NULL when not a single argument was a *value*.)

So, there is only one row in your data sample (the last one) that produces a non-NULL result for the `+`, and that result is `9`, which is what `SUM()` returns as well.