# avoid NULL reference result in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am running this query. Works fine however if `NULL` result found then it creates exception error in my application. How can I avoid `NULL` Reference

```
SELECT SUM(pointsEarned) as earned, SUM(pointsRedeemed) as redeemed 
FROM `salesData` 
WHERE dealerID = @dealerID and status = 'active'
```

Comment: Look at this: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php

Comment: Do you mean `pointsEarned` ,`pointsRedeemed` can be `NULL` ? If so, look at this answer showing an example using `COALESCE` https://stackoverflow.com/a/13132245/448144

Comment: Post the specific error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Sql Sum of multiple columns containing nulls return incorrect result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132222/why-does-sql-sum-of-multiple-columns-containing-nulls-return-incorrect-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COALESCE` Around your `SUM`.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(pointsEarned),0) earned, COALESCE(SUM(pointsRedeemed),0) redeemed 
FROM salesData 
WHERE dealerID = @dealerID
AND status = 'active'
```